# How to pass the value from onchange select via Ajax to wp function and display on page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a select field which display the type of odds. each odds from field call different value and this value needs to change and display on Odds.php using Ajax.

How can I achieve to pass the value of Select field via Ajax using jQuery and WP Functions?

Odds.php

```
<select id="typeOdds" class="uk-select">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Odds Type</option>
    <option value="spread">Spread</option>
    <option value="total">Total</option>
    <option value="moneyline">Moneyline</option>
</select>
```

and this is the variable that i need to change from my condition when odds type changed:

`$pregameodds->AwayPointSpread` into `$pregameodds->AwayMoneyLine`

This is my example of Ajax code but nowhere to go...

```
$('#typeOdds').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
           // my value from select field
        }
    });
});
```

**Updated my question:**

I don't see when I call the "typeOdds". But in the console.log and alert it was displaying my value.

My odds.js

```
jQuery('#typeOdds').on('change', function($) {
  var val = jQuery('#typeOdds').val();
  console.log( '_type is changed to ' + val );

  var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'type': 'post',
    'typeOdds': val
  };

  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert( 'Got this from the server: ' + response );
  });
});
```

My functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
  global $wpdb;
  $typeOdds = $_POST['typeOdds'];
  echo $typeOdds;
}
```

My condition to Odds.php

```
if ( $typeOdds == 'spread' ) {
  $spreadPoint = $pregameodds->AwayPointSpread;
} elseif ( my_action() == 'moneyline' ) {
  $moneylinePoint = $pregameodds->AwayMoneyLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just a few slight modifications to your code:

```
$('#typeOdds').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        data: {"typeOdds": $('#typeOdds').val()}, //this is where you pass the value
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        success: function(data) {
           // this is where you do things with the data you receive in return from the php script
           // so something like:
           alert(data); // data being whatever the php echo's out
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Updated the answer to reflect your typeOdds variable. I was posting myValue instead of typeOdds, so either I need to change mine to typeOdds, or you need to change the My Functions.php post variable to myValue.

Comment: i've updated my question.. i still don't see the value passing to my functions.php

Comment: as of now, im experiencing 400 bad request from admin-ajax.php